# Snowflake server name is different

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch server name on snowflake and it says
https://app.snowflake.com/europe-west4.gcp

When I try to connect to qliksense, the error is as follows -
"Connections are only allowed to *.snowflakecomputing.com hosts"

I believe I must've messed up the set-up somewhere but unable to figure out exactly what. This is a trial account I am exploring btw. I am newbie to snowflake and any help is appreciable. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Finding the Region and Locator for an Account](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#finding-the-region-and-locator-for-an-account)

> If you can connect to your Snowflake account, you can query the following context functions to identify the region and account locator for the Snowflake account you are connected to:
>
> - CURRENT_REGION retrieves the region in which your account is located.
> - CURRENT_ACCOUNT retrieves the account locator.

Account URL could also be copied using Snowsight UI:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-connect.html this will help

Comment: Thank you. after going through the whole documentation, I realized there are two versions here - one is the app UI and other is developer UI. I have been trying to access the app UI and here unable to fetch the server name and most of the features were disabled.